# SQL: Select Insert using ID from first Column

Tags: mysql, select, insert

So I'm in a situation where I currently have two tables, that are linked by some foreign key.

```
`table_a` (
    `table_id` int not null,
    `important_value varchar(128) not null,
);

`table_b` (
    `table_id` int not null,
    `table_a_id` int not null,
)
```

I want to move `important_value` into `table_b`, which has a reference to `table_a`.

Assuming that I use the following alter SQL

```
alter table `table_b` add column `important_value` varchar(128) not null;
```

How would I now insert the relevant `important_value` into `table_b` given it has reference to `table_a_id`?

Comment: Insult? Isn't there too much of that already these days?

Comment: Damn, you caught me. Edited to insert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
update table_b b join
       table_a a
       on b.table_a_id = a.table_id
    set b.important_value = a.important_value;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I have 9 minutes to do before I can accept an answer, but I'll be sure to make the return trip. Thanks!